# wcf not authentication connection to secured endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf

I have service and client application. Old version of service does not have any authorization and authentication. And i implement it using CustomRoleProvider and CustomPasswordValidator . It works greate. But i need that old client will be able to conect and perfom some simple action. I create some logic that give a user role "Unknown" if i cant get Identities. I Can anybody say where i should dig?

I use

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
   <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
</security>
```

I understand that problem in that old client think that there is no security at all. Maybe i need to create another end point. But it should use only one address.

Comment: Yes, you need another end point, one that's unsecured. I'm not sure, but you might be able to execute an redirect, when the authentication fails, to your unsecured endpoint

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it. How could i redirect to another endpoint.

Comment: This should tell you: http ://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get